# How to get the x, y of each pixel of the graph?

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have the following image:

[image]

**I need to complete 2 steps.**

**1 step.** Get the values (x, y) for each pixel of the graph. And as a result: the number of graphs is equal to the number of arrays containing objects {'x': x, 'y': y} for each pixel of the graph.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

**Step 2.** Each pixel array for each graph needs to be run in scipy.find_peaks and get peaks (maximum points for each graph).

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

img_gray = cv2.imread('photo.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('save.jpg', img_binary)

image = cv2.imread('save.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('save.jpg', image)


im = Image.open("save.jpg")
im = im.convert('RGB')

col_black = (0, 0, 0)
col_white = (255, 255, 255)

for y in range(im.size[1]):
    for x in range(im.size[0]):
        if sum(im.getpixel((x, y))) < 128:
            im.putpixel((x, y), (0, 0, 0))
        else:
            im.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))

point_start_array = []
for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        if im.getpixel((x, y)) == col_black and im.getpixel((x, y + 1)) == col_white:
            if len(point_start_array) > 4:
                break
            else:
                point_start_array.append({'x': x, 'y': y})

print(point_start_array)
```

**OUTPUT:** [{'x': 19, 'y': 161}, {'x': 19, 'y': 238}, {'x': 19, 'y': 260}, {'x': 19, 'y': 269}, {'x': 19, 'y': 282}]
[image]

Is it possible for each graph to throw 1 array x, the second y to throw in scipy.find_peaks and get peaks?

Comment: So you are having arrays that contain 4 points each and want to feed in scipy.find_peaks?

Comment: unclear... The way I understood it is: the input is the image, but maybe this is not the case?

Comment: @Manaclan, I haven't received an array of pixels for each graph yet. But I need to do this and run 2 arrays (x, y) in scipy for each graph.find_peaks to find peaks (maximum points). Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: @Vadim: please make your question more focused: you have at least 2 very different steps here. Getting the numerical data from the image and finding the peaks. Also, please provide the minimal code to read the image and set up everything.

Comment: @mozway, yes, there is an image at the input.

Comment: @mozway, I have corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv `connectedComponents` to get the points of the graph and some numpy tricks to get the `y` array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

im = cv2.imread('temp.png')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
binary = cv2.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
binary = ~binary
# Get connected components
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(binary)
graphs = []
for label in range(1,ret):
    mask = np.array(labels, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask[labels == label] = 255
    mask = mask.reshape((mask.shape[0], mask.shape[1], 1))
    X,Y = np.where(np.all(mask == 255,axis=2))
    graphs.append(Y)

for ys in graphs:
  peaks, _ = find_peaks(ys, height=0)
```

Though note that the one graph in your images is not fully connected i.e: there is one pixel that's missing to connect the graph. So instead of 5, there are 6 graphs. I would suggest using some image manipulation technique like erosion to connect the graph but it'll sacrifice some accuracy

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

im = cv2.imread('temp.png')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
binary = cv2.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# Erode the images to connect seperated parts
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)  
binary = cv2.erode(binary, kernel, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT) 
# Get connected components
binary = ~binary
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(binary)
graphs = []
for label in range(1,ret):
    mask = np.array(labels, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask[labels == label] = 255
    cv2.imwrite(f'{label}.jpg',mask)
    mask = mask.reshape((mask.shape[0], mask.shape[1], 1))
    X,Y = np.where(np.all(mask == 255,axis=2))
    graphs.append(Y)
for ys in graphs:
  peaks, _ = find_peaks(ys, height=0)
```

Comment: thank you, hello, is it possible to somehow link this graph (where 1 px is missing) using linear interpolation?

Comment: In my second code snippet I used erode to join the graph. Other method I could think of is writing your own implementation of Finding connected components with custom neighbor grid